# Which ppi is correct in iOS4 images (normal and high res)

Tags: iphone, image, ios4, ios

I want to add high res images in my iOS4 app. I already read this http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW2 and a lot of other pages but I did not find the answer which ppi my image should have.

Currently, I have an image for example button.png with 160ppi and 50x30px. Now I want to create a high res image named button@2x.png. Is it correct to use 326ppi and 100x60px?

I already had a look at other iOS open source apps but each app did it on a different way. Most apps used 72ppi for normal and high res. What is correct?

Thanks for your answers

Walter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be quite frank, I've not found a need to adjust pixel resolution for my images (i.e. I leave my Photoshop templates at 72 ppi and they're OK). If you just provide the correct *dimensions* for each format, the system will know how to deal with your images appropriately depending on the resolution of the device it's on.

Comment: +1. It doesn't matter what you put in there. 72 is a good standard that works well in almost every situation.

Comment: As you say, PPI is irrelevant - it's only ever a hint for anything that would use the image where real measurements mattered.

Comment: @Walter: glad to be of help. Be sure to click the green tick next to an answer to indicate that it's the best answer.